# fork into a branch?

Tags: git, github

A while back I forked a github repository.  Many changes since then have been made to both the original and the fork.

Now I would like to add the fork back to the original repository as a branch... preferably from the time when the fork was made (it should have been a branch, but, live and learn).

Can I do this?  The best I can think to do is make a new branch on the original and then copy and paste over the files from the current state of the fork.  I lose all of my history, but at least everything is together.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a new branch in your fork, then push from your fork's branch to the main repo. You can easily do this using the Github Pull Request feature if you want.

Answer (score 0):

When you fork a repository, you create completely new branches. Even if the name of the branch in your fork is `master` and in the original repository it's also `master`, for git they are completely unrelated branches (besides the fact that they share history). In fact, for git they have different names. One could be `origin/master` and the other could be `fork_origin/master`.

If you really care about the name (or if github matches names for pull-requests (I don't know if it does)), you can simply rename your branch:

```
git branch -m master some_other_name
```

Then you can push this to your forked repository and send a pull-request.

---

Side note: since it looks like that you are the owner of both repositories, you can also take a shortcut. You can simply add a remote that points to the original repository and push your branch (given a different name):

```
$ git remote add original_repo git@github.com:user/repo
$ git push original_repo master some_other_name
```